# how to configure a log file in json Getting error:ValueError: Unable to configure root logger

Tags: python, json, logging

Hello guys i have a json program which will give the log file in a json formate but i'm not able to get the output...This is the json file which is named as "logging.json"

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": false,
    "formatters": {
        "json": {
        "format": "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
            "()": "pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "json"
        }
    },

    "file_handler": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "level": "INFO",
            "formatter": "json",
            "filename": "Data-Generation.log",
            "mode": "a",
            "encoding": "utf8"
        },

    "root": {
       "level": "DEBUG",
       "handlers": ["console", "file_handler"]
    }
}
```

**now i'm try to access in my python program like this:**

```
fp = open('logging.json')
logging.config.dictConfig(json.load(fp))
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
fp.close()
logger.info("Logging is started")
```

**i'm getting this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\logging\config.py", line 753, in add_handlers
    logger.addHandler(self.config['handlers'][h])
  File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\logging\config.py", line 315, in __getitem__
    value = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
KeyError: 'file_handler'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\logging\config.py", line 634, in configure
    self.configure_root(root)
  File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\logging\config.py", line 786, in configure_root
    self.common_logger_config(root, config, incremental)
  File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\logging\config.py", line 770, in common_logger_config
    self.add_handlers(logger, handlers)
  File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\logging\config.py", line 755, in add_handlers
    raise ValueError('Unable to add handler %r' % h) from e
ValueError: Unable to add handler 'file_handler'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Codedata\scratch\Python\ManufactureDataWithDateRange\ActionHandler.py", line 17, in <module>
    logging.config.dictConfig(json.load(fp))
  File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\logging\config.py", line 792, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\logging\config.py", line 637, in configure
    'logger') from e
ValueError: Unable to configure root logger
```

**Note:** This is happens when i was trying to add the "streamHandler" in my json file before it was printing logs in a json format **i think there is a problem in "config.dictConfig"** i don't know...please help me with it..
**working program without "StreamHandler" is:**

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": false,
    "formatters": {
        "json": {
        "format": "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
            "()": "pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter"
        }
    }, 
"handlers": {
       "file_handler": {
           "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
           "level": "DEBUG",
           "formatter": "json",
           "filename": "Data-Generation.log",
           "encoding": "utf8"
       }
   },

   "root": {
       "level": "DEBUG",
       "handlers": ["file_handler"]
       }
     }
```

**This is correct Json format and printing the logs but want to remove all unwanted line from my log so i tried to include the "streamHnadler"please help me how to do it...Thanks**

Comment: Both, `console` and `file_handler` must be child elements of `handlers` in the json structure. In your first json with both handlers, `file_handler` is a top-level element instead; so when `dictConfig` tries to look up `file_handler` in section `handlers` it can't find it and raises a KeyError. Simply move `handlers`' closing bracket `},` from line 15 to line 24 and correct the trailing commas behind `file_handler` and `console` accordingly.

Comment: @shmee please can you do it here and tell where to add that commas because i did but its not working..

Comment: i have added it at 24 no line but still showing the same error i have check for all commas also its correct..not printing please help @shmee

Comment: I got it thnx...

Comment: Ah, the famed "I fixed it" but no solution posted..